# Having issue with creating Directory

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a directory with names which I already have. These names are saved as

```
$targetfolders[1] = "ABC"
$targetfolders[2] = "DEF"
$targetfolders[3] = "GHI"

New-Item c:\$targetfolders[1]\$targetfolders[2]\$targetfolders[3] -type directory
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PowerShell 3.0+ (and therefore .NET 4.0+):

```
New-Item [System.IO.Path]::Combine(@("C:\") + $targetFolders) -Type Directory
```

Otherwise,

```
$path = "C:\"; $targetFolders | % { $path = Join-Path $path $_ }
New-Item $path -Type Directory
```

Your mistake though was you didn't put your path in a string,

```
"c:\$($targetfolders[1])\$($targetfolders[2])\$($targetfolders[3])"
```

`$()` Inside a string will evaluate the content inside and replace it. Variable substitution also works (but not for arrays):

```
"c:\$folder1\$folder2\$folder3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the full path into a second variable and use that, like so:

```
$fullpath = "C:\"+($targetfolders)[1]+"\"+($targetfolders)[2]+"\"+($targetfolders)[3]
New-Item $fullpath -Type Directory
```

Answer (score 0):

With your folder names in an array you could use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) for building the path:

```psh
$targetfolders = 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'

$path = 'c:\{0}\{1}\{2}' -f $targetfolders

New-Item -Type Directory -Path $path
```

If you have other elements in your array you can mask them out by adjusting the indexes in the format string:

```psh
$targetfolders = 'foo', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'bar', 'GHI'

$path = 'c:\{1}\{2}\{4}' -f $targetfolders

New-Item -Type Directory -Path $path
```